# Hibernate oneToMany Abstract Class override ID

Tags: hibernate

I'm using JPA 1.0 so I am limited in what I can do but I still think it should be possible to do the following however I cant get it working...

```
Table CustomerA
    a_id

Table ProductB
    a_id
    b_id

Table ProductC
    a_id
    c_id

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue....
    private Long id;

    private String name;

 @ManyToOne()
 JoinColumn(name="a_id")
 private CustomerA customerA;

}
```

Now I want to create a subclass which can over ride the `Id` or create a composite Key based on the `PK` of `Table A` and the key of the derived table...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ProductB") 
public class ProductB extends AbstractProduct {

     //@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="B_ID") //Can only be used     with MappedSuperClass and also Emmbedded Objects
     //@Id //cant override the ID Column so that cant go here
    //PrimaryKeycolumn join not what i want here
    private Long productB_id;

    private String productName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerA") 
public class CustomerA
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue....
    @Column(name="a_id")
    private Long aId

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="customerA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AbstractProduct> product;
}
```

So essentially `CustomerA` can contain many products, but it will always only be of either `ProductB` or `ProductC`.  How can i override the `Id` in the subclass as you cant use `attributeoverride` and Entity, and if you use `@Entity` you must specify `@Id` whenever you specify an `@Entity`.  I've read the jpa wiki and it looks rather complicated and ott to achieve this in JPA 1.0, but i'm wondering if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to share a base class between your two products, so that you can reference them both in a single way.  In JPA/Hibernate that means creating a shared table that will contain the common elements of your Product, namely the reference to the CustomerA.

The way you can accomplish this is with the 'JOINED' inheritance strategy:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

The drawback of using this strategy is it may collide with your existing 'TABLE_PER_CLASS' stategy already used in your AbstractProduct base class.... although this may be the appropriate base class to use for this.  From what I remember, you cannot mix inheritance strategies.

Here's an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerA") 
public class CustomerA
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue....
    @Column(name="a_id")
    private Long aId

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customerA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AbstractProduct> product;
} 

@Entity
@Table(name="ProductB") 
public class ProductB extends AbstractProduct {

    private String specificProductBValue;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ProductC") 
public class ProductC extends AbstractProduct {

    private String specificProductCValue;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue....
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private CustomerA customerA;

}
```

Seems like you are almost there with your example, just need to use the correct inheritance strategy.

Also, this assumes that you do not have other Products that extend your AbstractProduct base class.  If you do and you don't want those referenced by your Customer, then you would have to reconsider your domain design.

Hope that helps.